# Why is Apache showing its default page when url is not FQDN?

Tags: apache-2.4, ubuntu-16.04

Why is Apache showing its default page when url is not Fully Qualified Domain Name? For example `www.example.com` show my Django app, but `example.com` or IP address or hostname shows the default Apache page.

```
ServerName www.example.com
ServerAlias example.com
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure `mysite.com` is not your domain. If it is, you may want to make that explicit...

Answer (score -1):

you need to unset your ServerName and set your multiples domains on ServerAlias (separated by space) Ex :

```
#ServerName DISABLED
ServerAlias example.com www.example.com web.example.com
```